# How to find entities by spring data with same values of different fields?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I look for short (one-method-long) solution of my problem.
I want to write query in spring data that does the same as:

```
select * from Users
where city = @EnteredData data OR homeTown = @EnteredData
```

I tried

```
List<User> findDistinctCity_findByHomeTown(String city);
```

I have no ideas how to find users whose city or homeTown is equal to given value in one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with the below version. I better write my own queries instead of trying to use the Spring Data generated DSL one

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.city = :city or u.homeTown = :city") public List<User> getUserInfo(@Param("city") String city);
```

Comment: I know this way. But i think it's dirty. I can use JDBC for jpql. But i have spring data and i want to use abstraction level.

Comment: This is the kind of use case @Query was introduced for in Spring Data. It is using Spring Data just fine.

Comment: This is the easiest way to go and that's why @Query annotation is for. U will be waiting enormous amount of time if u stick to method generates queries for all ur purpose.

Answer (score -1):

U can use method query, Add Or in query

```
List<User> findByCityOrHometowm(String name);
```

JpqL snippet will create as

```
where x.city= ?1 or x.hometown = ?2
```

Comment: That should require you to have two method arguments and pass in the name twice